# Which SoftLayer Permissions allow which actions?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The SoftLayer (IBM Cloud Infrastructure) API has a large set of permissions with names like:

```
{'keyName': 'ACCESS_ALL_GUEST', 'name': 'All Guest Access'}
```

or

```
{'keyName': 'SERVER_ADD', 'name': 'Add Server'}
```

These can all be retrieved using the API call
`client['SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission'].getAllObjects()`

However I can't find any cross reference to which permissions are needed to allow a user to perform any given function. For example, is "Add Server" only need for order a bare-metal server? That one might be considered somewhat self-explanatory, but many/most are not so obvious.

Is there such a cross-reference? So far we're having to resort to making guesses and trying to add things until an operation works, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can to use [SoftLayer_User_Permission_Action::getAllObjects](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Permission_Action/getAllObjects/)
this is not a cross reference, but you will get a description of the permission which you wished to use, the response will be a set of permissions as below:

```
{
    "createDate": null,
    "description": "Add new servers to the account.",
    "id": 1267,
    "key": "XX_1",
    "keyName": "SERVER_ADD",
    "modifyDate": null,
    "name": "Add Server"
},
{
    "createDate": null,
    "description": "Modify the account and company profile associated with this account.",
    "id": 1268,
    "key": "A_2",
    "keyName": "COMPANY_EDIT",
    "modifyDate": null,
    "name": "Edit Company Profile"
},
{
    "createDate": null,
    "description": "Upgrade any servers on the account.",
    "id": 1269,
    "key": "A_5",
    "keyName": "SERVER_UPGRADE",
    "modifyDate": null,
    "name": "Upgrade Server"
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd prefer a bit more detail, but this is still a significant help. For example, which permission is needed to order a VSI? I can't tell from just reading the descriptions.

Comment: to order a VSI you will need SERVER_ADD permission like mentioned in the  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581953/10480507)